# CKAN - Why I only get a result with the first 10 from Count

Tags: api, ckan

With the CKAN API query I get a count = 47 (thats correct) but only 10 results.

How do I get all (=47) results with the API query?

CKAN API Query:

```
https://suche.transparenz.hamburg.de/api/3/action/package_search?q=title:Fahrplandaten+(GTFS)&sort=score+asc
```

From source: *For me the page loads very slowly, patience

```
https://suche.transparenz.hamburg.de/dataset?q=hvv-fahrplandaten+gtfs&sort=score+desc%2Ctitle_sort+asc&esq_not_all_versions=true&limit=50&esq_not_all_versions=true
```

Answer (score 2):

The `count` shows only the total number of results found. You can change the total number of results returned by setting up limit and row parameters. e.g https://suche.transparenz.hamburg.de/api/3/action/package_search?q=title:Fahrplandaten+(GTFS)&sort=score+asc&rows=100. The `row` limit is 1000 per query. You can find more info [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search)

Comment: if you have more than 1000 packages, just trow request with rows=1000 and throw a second request with param start=1000  will give you the other package. https://suche.transparenz.hamburg.de/api/3/action/package_search?q=title:Fahrplandaten+(GTFS)&sort=score+asc&rows=1000&start=1000